# Resque job undefined method 'current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

It's my first attempt at Resque and doing background jobs, and I'm kind of stuck.

I have two issues at hand.

1. It gives me the error

   ```
   undefined local variable or method `current_user'
   ```
2. I am not sure if what I am pushing to the worker is indeed the most correct thing.

Here is my code:

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
  def trial
@schedule = current_user.schedules.new
if @schedule.save
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  @client = Buffer::Client.new(user.token)
  Resque.enqueue(ScheduleTweets, @client)
  @schedule.update_attribute(:trial, true)
  flash[:notice] = "success"
  redirect_to :back
else 
  flash[:alert] = "Try again."
  redirect_to :back
end
```

end

and the worker:

**apps/workers/schedule_tweets.rb**

```
class ScheduleTweets
 @queue = :schedules_queue

 def self.perform(client)
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  client = Buffer::Client.new(user.token)
  @list = List.first(6)
  @profiles = client.profiles
  @profile_ids = profiles.map(&:id)
  @list.each do |list|
    client.create_update(body: {text: "#{list.text}", profile_ids: @profile_ids })
  end
 end
end 

end
```

my thought process is that the client is the core of the entire process and should thus be the one. However @profile_ids also contains anywhere from 1-5 values.

When I run the task I get the undefined local variable or method 'current_user'. How do I fix that, also am I doing it right by choosing the @client as the thing to add?

Comment: current_user is a helper method I guess. am I right? if yes then check if it is defined or not

Comment: @CbaBhusal I moved user = User.find(params[:id]) to def trial and changed current_user.schedules.new to user.schedules.new. The new error I experience now however is "undefined local variable or method `params'"

Comment: I think params is available only when http request is made,viz. getm post, etc and only in controller and views

Comment: @CbaBhusal any idea on how I can turn this code into a resque job then?

Comment: do you use pry-rails debugging tool
put a breakpoint and see whats going on
or try to just point a user for test's sake like below
`user = User.find(1)
client = Buffer::Client.new(user.token)`

Comment: just like you sent `@client` via argument I suggest you to send the user_id too instead of invoking the params because params are not available in workers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
schedules_controller.rb

```
def trial
  @schedule = current_user.schedules.new
  if @schedule.save
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    @client = Buffer::Client.new(user.token)
    Resque.enqueue(ScheduleTweets, user.id)
    @schedule.update_attribute(:trial, true)
    flash[:notice] = "success"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Try again."
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

and the worker:

apps/workers/schedule_tweets.rb

```
class ScheduleTweets
  @queue = :schedules_queue

  def self.perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    client = Buffer::Client.new(user.token)
    @list = List.first(6)
    @profiles = client.profiles
    @profile_ids = @profiles.map(&:id)
    @list.each do |list|
      client.create_update(body: {text: "#{list.text}", profile_ids: @profile_ids })
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Arguments
--- 21
...
Exception
NameError
Error
undefined local variable or method `params' for ScheduleTweets:Class

as you can see it does find the id in the argument, however still returns the param problem.

Comment: this one:  /schedule_tweets.rb:5:in `perform'

However it have kept saying the same line, even though the code line chagnes.

Comment: did you restart the server as well as the resque service? try this

Comment: progress. Now it says undefined local variable or method `profiles' for ScheduleTweets:Class
/Users/sja/workspace/prepopulate/app/workers/schedule_tweets.rb:9:in `perform'

Comment: is it profile or profiles. can a client have multiple profiles?
or try `@profiles = client.try(profiles)`

Comment: What is there is correct. I tried bringing the code back into the controller and it ran perfectly.

Comment: I think the main problem has been that the server has needed to get restarted between changes. I tried that, didn't work. Then I restarted redis, resque and rails and now it worked. Sweet!